# How to get day names between to dates using for loop in php

Tags: php, date

I write following code to get results: -

```
$date_from = date('2018-12-14');
$date_from = strtotime($date_from);
$date_to = date('2018-12-16');
$date_to = strtotime($date_to);
for ($i=$date_from; $i<=$date_to; $i+=86400)
{
    echo $date = date("d-m-Y", $i).' - ';
    echo $dayName = date('l', strtotime($date)).'<br>';
}
```

My expected results are as under: -

```
14-12-2018 - Friday 
15-12-2018 - Saturday 
16-12-2018 - Sunday
```

But what I am getting is: -

```
14-12-2018 - Thursday 
15-12-2018 - Thursday 
16-12-2018 - Thursday
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are mixing up the `echo` and assignments, you are ending up from

```
echo $date = date("d-m-Y", $i).' - ';
```

With `$date` as `14-12-2018-` (the extra `-` on the end).  When you try and convert this back to a date in the next line it will fail.

Separate them out and it should work...

```
for ($i=$date_from; $i<=$date_to; $i+=86400)
{
    $date = date("d-m-Y", $i);
    $dayName = date('l', strtotime($date));
    echo $date .'-'. $dayName.'<br>';
}
```

Comment: The magic number `86400` is not typically endorsed because of timezone concerns in fringe cases.

Answer (score 2):

I find using `DateTime()` and it's related classes makes this much easier. Just create a start and end date with an interval of ne day and use then loop through them to output the days.

```
$start = new DateTime('2018-12-14');
$end   = (new DateTime('2018-12-16'))->modify('+1 day');
$interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
$period = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);
foreach ($period as $date) {
    echo "{$date->format('d-m-Y - l')}<br>";
}
```

`$start` is a [`DateTime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object and represents the starting day. `$end` is the last day of the loop. You have to add one day to it as `DatePeriod` loops are not inclusive of the last day. `$interval` is a [`DateInterval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) object that represents the interval we want to loop through. In this case a period of one day. `$period` is a [`DatePeriod()`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php) object and represents all of that information in an iterable object. From there you just loop through it, and with the `DateTime()` object you are provided with, you simply format as normal.

Result:

```
14-12-2018 - Friday
15-12-2018 - Saturday
16-12-2018 - Sunday
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/1070148)

Note: this solution rakes daylight savings time and leap year into consideration.